# "cannot convert type 'system.linq.igrouping<string,Models.CashCall> to Models.CashCall"

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

My code is as below

```
 public string GetCashCallsbyDate(DateTime _date)
    {
        using (var context = new TildaDbContext())
        {
           List<CashCall> cashcallName = new List<CashCall>();
            try
            {
                CashCall cashCall = new CashCall();
                var cashcalls = context.CashCalls.Where(d => d.Date == _date).GroupBy(g => g.CashCallName).ToList();
                foreach (var data in cashcalls)
                {
                    cashCall = data;   // error here
                    cashcallName.Add(cashCall);
                }
                string CashCallsbyDate = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cashcallName);
                return CashCallsbyDate;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting compile time error as

> cannot convert type 'system.linq.igrouping to
>   Models.CashCall

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `data` on each loop is a group of one or more `CashCall` objects that share the same name.

Presumably you are grouping for a reason, so it may not be appropriate just to ungroup the data (otherwise the `GroupBy` would be completely redundant) by loopnig over contents in each group as suggested elsehwhere. So you could do something like just get the first item in the group. For example:

```
foreach (var data in cashcalls)
{
    cashCall = data.First(); // Gets the first element in the group.
    cashcallName.Add(cashCall);
}
```

You may want to aggregate the data from all the items in the group and create a new CashCall object based on that aggregation, but that is entirely up to your use case.

If you do want all the `cashCall` objects, but just want all the ones with the same name grouped together, it would be better to use an `OrderBy` instead of the `GroupBy`.

Comment: Finally achieved it. Thanks a lot.